# CODING Q based on Dataframes and Series and dictionaries

Tags: pandas, numpy

It would be interesting to see if there is any evidence of a link between vaccine effectiveness and sex of the child. Calculate the ratio of the number of children who contracted chickenpox but were vaccinated against it (at least one varicella dose) versus those who were vaccinated but did not contract chicken pox. Return results by sex.

This function should return a dictionary in the form of (use the correct numbers):

```
{"male":0.2,
"female":0.4}
```

Note: To aid in verification, the chickenpox_by_sex()['female'] value the autograder is looking for starts with the digits 0.0077.
PLEASE WRITE A FUNCTIONING CODE FOR THE SAME.

Answer (score 0):

### Try the following code:

Read the given dataset using the following code

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('assets/NISPUF17.csv',index_col=0)
df
```

Main code

```
def chickenpox_by_sex():
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    male_df=df[df['SEX']==1]           
    vac_m=male_df[male_df['P_NUMVRC']>=1]  
    cp_m=vac_m[vac_m['HAD_CPOX']==1]       
    counts_cp_m=cp_m['SEX'].count()
    ncp_m=vac_m[vac_m['HAD_CPOX']==2]
    counts_ncp_m=ncp_m['SEX'].count()
    male=counts_cp_m/counts_ncp_m
    female_df=df[df['SEX']==2]               
    vac_f=female_df[female_df['P_NUMVRC']>=1]  
    cp_f=vac_f[vac_f['HAD_CPOX']==1]       
    counts_cp_f=cp_f['SEX'].count()
    ncp_f=vac_f[vac_f['HAD_CPOX']==2]
    counts_ncp_f=ncp_f['SEX'].count()
    female=counts_cp_f/counts_ncp_f
    ratio_dict={"male":male,"female":female}
    return ratio_dict
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

Check using the following code

```
chickenpox_by_sex()['female']
```

Final code to complete this

```
assert len(chickenpox_by_sex())==2, "Return a dictionary with two items, the first for males and the second for females."
```

=> [SEX] -> sex=1 (male);  sex=2 (female)

=> [HAD_COP] -> contracted chicken pox = 1; not contracted chicken pox = 2

=> [P_NUMVRC]>=1 -> given one or more doses

*ratio(male) = (vaccinated and contracted chicken pox)/(vaccinated and not contracted chicken pox)

*ratio(female) = (vaccinated and contracted chicken pox)/(vaccinated and not contracted chicken pox)

Variable names:

male        - male data frame

vac_m       - vaccinated male

cp_m        - vaccinated and contracted chickenpox (male)

counts_cp_m - counts of vaccinated and contracted chickenpox

ncp_m       - vaccinated and not contracted chickenpox (male)

counts_ncp_m - vaccinated and not contracted chickenpox

Similarly for females.

Answer (score 0):

CORRECT SOLUTION.

```
def chickenpox_by_sex():
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_csv("NISPUF17.csv")

    maleDf = df[df["SEX"] ==1]
    doses1 = maleDf[maleDf["P_NUMVRC"] >= 1]
    chichkenPox1_1 = doses1[doses1["HAD_CPOX"] == 1]
    count1_1 = chichkenPox1_1["SEX"].count()
    chichkenPox1_2 = doses1[doses1["HAD_CPOX"] == 2]
    count1_2 = chichkenPox1_2["SEX"].count()
    resultMale = count1_1/count1_2

    femaleDf = df[df["SEX"] == 2]
    doses2 = femaleDf[femaleDf["P_NUMVRC"] >= 1]
    chichkenPox2_1 = doses2[doses2["HAD_CPOX"] == 1]
    count2_1 = chichkenPox2_1["SEX"].count()
    chichkenPox2_2 = doses2[doses2["HAD_CPOX"] == 2]
    count2_2 = chichkenPox2_2["SEX"].count()
    resultFemale = count2_1/count2_2

    dict = {"male":resultMale,
            "female":resultFemale
        }   

    return dict
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works as well:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
def chickenpox_by_sex():
 df=pd.read_csv('assets/NISPUF17.csv')
 c_vaccinated=df[df['P_NUMVRC']>0] 
 menstats=c_vaccinated[c_vaccinated['SEX']==1]
 mnocpox=len(menstats[menstats['HAD_CPOX']==2])
 menratio=len(menstats[menstats['HAD_CPOX']==1])/mnocpox
 
 
 wstats=c_vaccinated[c_vaccinated['SEX']==2]
 wnocpox=len(wstats[wstats['HAD_CPOX']==2])  
 wratio=len(wstats[wstats['HAD_CPOX']==1])/wnocpox
 ratios={'male':menratio,'female':wratio}

 return ratios
chickenpox_by_sex()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

def chickenpox_by_sex():
    df = pd.read_csv('assets/NISPUF17.csv')
    df = df.drop(df[df.HAD_CPOX == 77].index)
    df = df.drop(df[df.HAD_CPOX == 99].index)
    df = df.dropna(subset=['P_NUMVRC'])

    df.loc[df['HAD_CPOX'] == 1, 'HAD_CPOX'] = 'YES'
    df.loc[df['HAD_CPOX'] == 2, 'HAD_CPOX'] = 'NO'

    df.loc[df['SEX'] == 1, 'SEX'] = 'male'
    df.loc[df['SEX'] == 2, 'SEX'] = 'female'

    df.loc[df['P_NUMVRC'] == 2.0, 'P_NUMVRC'] = 1
    df.loc[df['P_NUMVRC'] == 3.0, 'P_NUMVRC'] = 1

    df = df[['SEX', 'P_NUMVRC', 'HAD_CPOX']].round(decimals=0)

    dfm = df[df['SEX'] == 'male']
    dfmVac = dfm[dfm['P_NUMVRC'] == 1.0]
    mPoxVacYes = len(dfmVac[dfmVac['HAD_CPOX'] == 'YES'])
    mPoxVacNo = len(dfmVac[dfmVac['HAD_CPOX'] == 'NO'])

    dff = df[df['SEX'] == 'female']
    dffVac = dff[dff['P_NUMVRC'] == 1.0]
    fPoxVacYes = len(dffVac[dffVac['HAD_CPOX'] == 'YES'])
    fPoxVacNo = len(dffVac[dffVac['HAD_CPOX'] == 'NO'])

    ratioM = mPoxVacYes/float(mPoxVacNo)
    ratioF = fPoxVacYes/float(fPoxVacNo)

    result = {'male': ratioM * 100, 'female': ratioF * 100}

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('assets/NISPUF17.csv', usecols = ['HAD_CPOX', 'SEX', 'P_NUMVRC']).dropna().reset_index()
    
    def chickenpox_by_sex():
        girls = df[df.SEX == 2]
        girls_had = girls[(girls.HAD_CPOX == 1) & (girls.P_NUMVRC > 0.0)]
        girls_not_had = girls[(girls.HAD_CPOX == 2) &(girls.P_NUMVRC > 0.0)]        
        girls_ratio = len(girls_had)/len(girls_not_had)
    
        boys = df[df.SEX == 1]
        boys_had = boys[(boys.HAD_CPOX == 1) & (boys.P_NUMVRC > 0.0)]
        boys_not_had = boys[(boys.HAD_CPOX == 2) &(boys.P_NUMVRC > 0.0)]
        boys_ratio = len(boys_had)/len(boys_not_had)
    
        result = {"male": round(boys_ratio, ndigits=4),
                  "female":round(girls_ratio, ndigits = 4)}
        return result
        
    chickenpox_by_sex()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please add some description explaining what is does and how it solves the problem or add comments in the source code at appropriate places.

Answer (score 0):

```
def chickenpox_by_sex():
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    df = pd.read_csv("assets/NISPUF17.csv", index_col= 0)
    Pox = df[['SEX', 'HAD_CPOX','P_NUMVRC']].dropna()
    male_pox = Pox[(Pox['SEX']== 1) & (Pox['HAD_CPOX']== 1) & (Pox['P_NUMVRC'] > 0)]
    male_nopox = Pox[(Pox['SEX']== 1) & (Pox['HAD_CPOX']== 2) & (Pox['P_NUMVRC'] > 0)]
    fmale_pox = Pox[(Pox['SEX']== 2) & (Pox['HAD_CPOX']== 1) & (Pox['P_NUMVRC'] > 0)]
    fmale_nopox = Pox[(Pox['SEX']== 2) & (Pox['HAD_CPOX']== 2) & (Pox['P_NUMVRC'] > 0)]
    dic =   {"male":len(male_pox)/len(male_nopox),
    "female":len(fmale_pox)/len(fmale_nopox)}
    return  dic
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

Comment: Please explain this answer.